# multiprocessing pool python

Tags: python, hash, multiprocessing, pool

I would like to hash all files of a shared folder (all files in all sub folders). I would like to do this with multiprocessing pool, but I don't know how to call the function that does the calculation. The code below prints nothing (no errors), I can't use pool.map because I pass one file at a time to the function. Can you help me? Thank you very much.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import hashlib


def hashfile(fp):
    with open(fp, 'rb') as file:
        bytes = file.read()
        hash_file = hashlib.sha1(bytes).hexdigest()
        print(fp, hash_file)


def testProcessPool(share_input):
    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(share_input):
            for f in files:
                pool.apply_async(hashfile, os.path.join(root, f))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    testProcessPool('/Users/gm/Desktop/test')
```

---

Ok, thanks. I'm doing all this to find duplicate files (that's why I use a dictionary, see code below) and I have to try to make the code as fast as possible. I have many shares and some are even 150GB. With the threads I have not increased performance much, I hope to succeed with the processes.

```
def testProcessPool(share_input):
    diz = dict()
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        for r in pool.imap_unordered(hashfile, get_files(share_input)):
            if not r[1] in diz.keys():
                diz[r[1]] = r[0]
            else:
                diz[r[1]] = diz[r[1]] + '|' + r[0]
    for k, v in diz.items():
        print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd slightly change the code.

- create a generator that yields files (using `os.path.join`)
- use `Pool.imap_unordered` to call the hash computing function

```py
import os
import hashlib
from multiprocessing import Pool


def hashfile(fp):
    with open(fp, 'rb') as f:
        hash_file = hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest()
    return fp, hash_file


def get_files(inp):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inp):
        for f in files:
            yield os.path.join(root, f)

def testProcessPool(share_input):
    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        for r in pool.imap_unordered(hashfile, get_files(share_input)):
            print(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testProcessPool('/usr/')
```

Prints:

```
...

('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsvn_client-1.so.1.0.0', '86a1d993385993d0bf09346502295c1663e2e6e8')
('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3', '50966c2c9147b1e4af587599de81551d7223e152')
('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.32', 'd828cc5f429c1e2b124ebb50ee953ee9dae99c45')
('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsvn_subr-1.so.1.0.0', '200dedc1dfd66d7cc13a787f023678fc055a3658')
('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2.0.63', '0a314040f5dab8f7de474ba5b265c7e0bc7c75de')

...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me what is the ideal number of processes in the pool if multiprocessing.cpu_count=4? Can I use more than 4 processes (os Windows 11) or does it make no sense? I would also like to store the hashes in a dictionary. Is that a problem? Do i have to use lock/unlock?

Comment: @pacopyc You're doing CPU and IO heavy task (computing hashes, reading from disk) so using more that 4 processes doesn't make sense to me.  You can store the computed hashes to dictionary without lock, just instead `print(r)` do `my_dict[r[0]] = r[1]` (for example)

Comment: I don't understand, I've been running the script for over 5 hours and it still hasn't finished. I'm using 4 processes since cpu_count = 4, but the CPU is working at 5-6%, no more, while the memory is at about 75%. It seems clear to me that I'm not using the CPU. What do you think about it? Without multithreads or multiprocessing it takes 8 hours to run. What can I do to make it faster?

Comment: @pacopyc: This line `hash_file = hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest()` is simply an example to show how it can be done. In your code you should *not* read the whole file in at once (`f.read()`) but instead read it in chunks in a loop and use the `update()` method on the hash object to progressively develop the hash result.

Comment: @pacopyc: Using sha1 as a tool to find duplicate files is overkill and very inefficient. Use a fast non-cryptographic hash with a suitably wide output for your use case -- specifically how many files you'll be examining.